# Change the default timezone variable_get from views

Tags: 7, views, datetime

What I want is to change the way **drupal views** get the site's timezone setting. I want to set it manually in code.

Searching through the files I noticed that the function "`views_get_timezone()`" in `sites/all/modules/views/includes/handlers.inc @1182` (drupal 7) is responsible for getting the timezone and setting the `session.time_zone` in mysql, but when I change it nothing happens.

Any suggestion anyone for this or any similar solution? I just want to make a site with multiple timezones for anonymous users so I want to change the session.time_zone in mysql according the user location.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the time zone, the option is available in admin menu in:

- admin/settings/date-time in Drupal 6
- admin/config/regional/settings in Drupal 7

And it can be defined in **settings.php** as **date_default_timezone**

It can be accessed in Database in variables table too

```
SELECT *  FROM variable WHERE name LIKE  '%timezone%'
```

Comment: Like I said I want to change it in code overriding the timezone default setting.